# MockWebServer: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spock, okhttp, mockwebserver

Trying MockWebServer for the first time on a Groovy/Spring project that uses Spock for unit testing.

I added MockWebServer dependencies as directed (I had to add the second line myself to avoid errors, but it's not documented:

```
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.0.0")
testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.40")
```

I have a basic Spock test that looks like this:

```
def 'server'() {
    setup:
    MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer()

    expect:
    server
}
```

But it fails with this output:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.Util.immutableListOf([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;

    at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.<init>(MockWebServer.kt:176)
```

Is there another dependency I'm missing? Does MockWebServer not play well with Groovy and Spock?

For what it's worth, using version 3.1.4 seems to work:

```
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.14.2")
```

(I'm a first time user of MockWebServer)

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.0.0")
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0")
```

With MockWebServer your OkHttp dependency must be the same version.

Comment: I see I was missing the dependency to the `okhttp` library.  Thank you!!

Comment: It's not working for me. After i moved to Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9 code that working previously started not working. I tried gradle versions up and down, re-downloaded old project, changed mockwebserver, and okhttp versions but still not working. The line i get error is `mockWebServer = MockWebServer()`

Comment: @Thracian I think you might need to report a bug against Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, I found the solution in version, just change the version to "3.7.0" and it's work fine.

there is some discussion about version changing to "3.4.1" but this version got the problem (Cannot inherit from final class) that discussed at this issue :
https://github.com/andrzejchm/RESTMock/issues/56
so the safest version is "3.7.0" :D

just notice that both versions should be the same..
change your to dependencies to below:

```
//mock retrofit
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.7.0")
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0")
//if your source code is java
testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.40")
```